# GEB and GSTRING both use $

Tags: groovy, geb, gstring

I have a SQL which is evaluated during runtime:

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID FROM USER_DB WHERE USER_DB_ID = ${ -> this._session.usr_id}"
```

This SQL is fed by `ConfigSlurper` read through properties file in GEB page module.

```
slurper = new ConfigSlurper()
def props = slurper.parse(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(currentPageProperties))
propValue = props.SQL[propKey]
dbRows = _db.rows(propValue.toString())
```

When I execute this the $ is replaced with GEB $ which gets the page info, and retrieves `value = [:]`, and thus the SQL fails.

The value I referred above is the output for GSTRING replacement -

```
"SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID FROM USER_DB WHERE USER_DB_ID = [:]"
```

I am having this entire within content and doing the check in at checkers

```
    static content = {
verifyElements { ... } }
```

When doing a debug, I could see the ${} to be replaced with GEB page like BrowsePage.groovy, which is normal for $() in GEB.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? The problem with this sort of construct generally occurs because the `GString` is not being evaluated where you thought it was. If you can show us some specifics we might be able to identify where that misplacement is occurring.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "SQL is fed by `ConfigSlurper` read through properties file in GEB page module"? Also what do you mean by "When I execute this the $ is replaced with GEB $ which gets the page info, and retrieves `value = [:]`". What is `value`? What is page info? Showing the code wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: I extremely apologize for the delay. I have edited my original post with details.

Comment: Just to let you all know, I could not fix this issue by any means. Used GString templates as a temporary solution to get around this issue.